# updating chrome driver on google colab

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

How can I install https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip on google colab ?

When I want to use selenium I got this error :
WARNING:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:The chromedriver version (90.0.4430.212) detected in PATH at /usr/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (116.0.5845.96);
currently, chromedriver 116.0.5845.96 is recommended for chrome 116.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry